# Ruby 2.2 Hash#reject returning Hash for inheriting classes?

Tags: ruby

In the process of upgrading from Ruby 1.9.3 to Ruby 2.2.3 (MRI), I've found an issue that affects any class that inherits from `Hash`. If you call `#reject` on the instance of a class that inherits from `Hash`, it will always return a `Hash` instead of an instance of the class that invoked it.

For example, given the following code:

```
class CustomHash < Hash
  def count_in_english
    "There are #{self.count} items in this hash."
  end
end
```

For Ruby 1.9.3, the following succeeds:

```
1.9.3-p547 :060 > hash = CustomHash.new
 => {} 
1.9.3-p547 :061 > hash[1] = 'a'
 => "a" 
1.9.3-p547 :062 > hash[2] = 'b'
 => "b" 
1.9.3-p547 :063 > hash[3] = 'c'
 => "c" 
1.9.3-p547 :064 > odds_only_hash = hash.reject { |k,v| k % 2 == 0 }
 => {1=>"a", 3=>"c"} 
1.9.3-p547 :065 > odds_only_hash.count_in_english
 => "There are 2 items in this hash."
1.9.3-p547 :066 > odds_only_hash.class
 => CustomHash
```

But in Ruby 2.2.3:

```
2.2.3 :019 > hash = CustomHash.new
 => {} 
2.2.3 :020 > hash[1] = 'a'
 => "a" 
2.2.3 :021 > hash[2] = 'b'
 => "b" 
2.2.3 :022 > hash[3] = 'c'
 => "c" 
2.2.3 :023 > odds_only_hash = hash.reject { |k,v| k % 2 == 0 }
 => {1=>"a", 3=>"c"} 
2.2.3 :024 > odds_only_hash.count_in_english
NoMethodError: undefined method `count_in_english' for {1=>"a", 3=>"c"}:Hash
    from (irb):24
    from /Users/davidelner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
2.2.3 :025 > odds_only_hash.class
 => Hash
```

After doing a little searching, it looks like [this is known by the Ruby devs](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/03/10/regression-of-hash-reject-in-ruby-2-1-1/), was [discussed a little bit](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9223), and detailed in [this blog post](http://blog.sorah.jp/2014/03/10/hash-reject-regression-in-ruby211). This change has also broken Rails' `HashWithIndifferentAccess` as per [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14188), for which they issued [a pull request for Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14198) (yet remains broken in Rails 3.2.22?)

Clearly this behavior caught a lot of people off guard, and the change sounds ludicrous considering how it breaks the known Ruby gem universe (including Rails, Hashie, etc) that depend on this fundamental idea that objects shouldn't unexpectedly change type.

My question, for some of the better informed Ruby devs, is:

- Is Ruby committed to the idea that in Ruby 2.2.3, and all future versions, `Hash#reject` will always return a `Hash`? (As opposed to an instance of the class that invoked this function? e.g. 1.9.3 C source `return rb_hash_delete_if(rb_obj_dup(hash));`)
- If so, why is this default behavior now? Isn't this effectively 'sealing' `#reject`, and breaking reasonable expectations that using these `Enumerable` functions will still return you an object of the same type?
- Also, if so, how are developers expected to accommodate for this change in behavior? (Are we all expected to do exactly as the Rails team did?)

Comment: I think this falls into the general consensus of not inheriting from core classes. [Nice Article](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes)

Comment: Aren't the first two questions answered by the comments on the linked Ruby bug? 1. Yes., 2. Because the previous behavior was wrong. See its counterpart `Hash#select` which always returns an instance of `Hash` - even in 1.9.3 and previous versions.

Comment: Make no mistake, this is NOT a specialization of `Hash`. You can tell this is the case because the derived class merely uses the underlying `Hash` instance and has no other relationship to it. I think the fundamental problem here is that your subclass of `Hash` does not REALLY have an "is-a" relationship to `Hash`. It's merely implemented in terms of a `Hash` and it's clear that you want it to have a similar interface to that of `Hash`, but that alone is not a good enough reason to use inheritance. This is clearly a "has-a" relationship.

Comment: I agree how I'm using `Hash` in the above test case maybe not be the quintessential example of how to use inheritance. However, if one wants a class that can store values like a `Hash`, with additional custom 'helper' functions, how would one accomplish that? Even if composition is desirable, it escapes me on how you could leverage it here without inheriting from `Hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***CAVEAT!*** I am not a "better informed Ruby dev" and this is the first I've looked at this problem.

Looking at the commit history, this was a deliberate change.

```
commit 740535f843d65be45732e45b9fc07eadc4d63ba7
Author: nobu <nobu@b2dd03c8-39d4-4d8f-98ff-823fe69b080e>
Date:   Wed Dec 11 07:01:29 2013 +0000

    hash.c: reject should return a plain hash

    * hash.c (rb_hash_reject): return a plain hash, without copying
      the class, default value, instance variables, and taintedness.
      they had been copied just by accident.
      [ruby-core:59045] [Bug #9223]
```

[Bug #9223](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9223) has [Matz accepting the change of `Hash#reject`](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9223#note-6).

> I accept this behavior change. #reject should not copy instance variables etc. just like #select.

It seems it was intended for 2.2, but scrubbing it from 2.1 was flubbed.

It seems copying the class and the rest was an accident.  The change was made to make Hash methods more consistent with each other.

---

> ***How are developers expected to accommodate for this change in behavior? (Are we all expected to do exactly as the Rails team did?)***

The simple answer is to switch to `hash.dup.delete_if` to retain the same behavior across all versions.

Alternatively you could override `Hash#reject` in your sub-classes to retain the old behavior, but then your hash sub-classes would be breaking the new `Hash#reject` interface.

---

IMO the devs made a mistake.  The behavior of `Hash#reject` was desirable.  Methods should not make method calls on their own hard coded class name.  Methods should strive to retain the class of their invocant.  Otherwise you have the situation where sub-classes have to write wrappers around everything to avoid accidentally returning a parent object to the unsuspecting user.

It doesn't matter if it's an isa or a hasa relationship.  That is an internal implementation issue which should be invisible to the external user of your objects.

If consistency was desired, the behavior of `Hash#select` should have been changed to match.